# Enviar um array em JSON com aspas simples

Tags: php, laravel, array, api, lumen

Estou fazendo integração de uma api em Laravel, tenho que enviar um POST segundo a documentação da api com o seguinte body

```
{
      "token": "TOKEN DA APLICACAO",
      "email": "enviou@enviou.com.br",
      "frete": "0",
      "carrinho": '[{
                  "produto":"Produto 1",
                  "quantidade":"1",
                  "preco":"10.92",
                  "imagem":"http://site.com.br/foto.jpg",
                  "url":"http://site.com.br/produto"
                  }]'
  }
```

porem,o body que estou enviando é assim

```
{"token":"xxxxxxx","email":"eduardo@eduardo.com.br","frete":"0","carrinho":[{"produto":"computador","quantidade":"1","preco":"3000.00","imagem":"http:site.com.br/foto.jpg","url":"http//loja.dooca.local/computador"}]}
```

eu estou populando esse array da seguinte forma:

```
 $checkouts = [
                'token' => 'xxxxxx'),
                'email' => $checkout->getCustomer()->getEmail(),
                'frete' => '0',
                'carrinho' => [],
            ];

            foreach ($checkout->getItems() as $item) {
                $checkouts['carrinho'][] = [
                    'produto' => $item->getName(),
                    'quantidade' => strval($item->getQuantity()),
                    'preco' => $item->getPrice(),
                    'imagem' => 'http://site.com.br/foto.jpg',
                    'url' => $item->getUrl(),

               ];
```

O problema é que essa api só aceita se na parte do carrinho tiver aspas simples antes dos colchetes e não consigo botar de jeito nenhum...
como por exemplo assim  "carrinho": **'**[{

Comment: Não tem sentido, como já "diziam", **algo de errado não está certo**, se `carrinho:` precisa receber uma "STRING" com um formato de JSON ou é porque o autor da API fez algo gravíssimo. Como você não apresentou a parte do envio e nem como usou o json_encode então não tem como ninguém lhe responder de forma razoavel, e não posso chutar uma resposta, afinal o site não é para isto. Dê mais detalhes.

Comment: Exatamente, na documentação só é aceito o envio do body nesse molde:
  {
      "token": "TOKEN DA APLICACAO",
      "email": "enviou@enviou.com.br",
      "frete": "0",
      "carrinho": '[{
                  "produto":"Produto 1",
                  "quantidade":"1",
                  "preco":"10.92",
                  "imagem":"http://site.com.br/foto.jpg",
                  "url":"http://site.com.br/produto"
                  }]'
  }

O envio esta assim:

Api::enviou()->checkout()->post($checkouts);
estou mandando aquele array acima..que seria o certo..

Comment: Eu não tenho acesso a tal documentação para saber se é isto ou se você entendeu algo errado, e não adicione códigos no campo de "comentários", olha na pergunta, tem um link chamado "editar", corrija a pergunta com os detalhes minimos que faltam para podermos entender o problema, não vai adiantar eu ficar chutando respostas igual a quem já respondeu, pra se ter uma resposta você tem que "nos ajudar" a ajuda-lo, mostra o que fez de forma compreensivel, pedaços soltos de códigos que não fazem nada não ajudarão.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?

Veja se isso ajuda você.

```
$array = [];

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $array[] = [
        'produto' => 'nome item',
        'quantidade' => 12,
        'preco' => 12.12,
        'imagem' => 'http://site.com.br/foto.jpg',
        'url' => 'http://site.com.br/',
    ];
}

$carrinho = json_encode($array);

$checkouts = [
    'token' => 'xxx',
    'email' => 'email@servidor.com.br',
    'frete' => '0',
    'carrinho' => "$carrinho"
];
```

**Saída**

```
array(4) {
  ["token"]=>
  string(3) "xxx"
  ["email"]=>
  string(21) "email@servidor.com.br"
  ["frete"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["carrinho"]=>
  string(1271) "[{"produto":"nome item","quantidade":12,"preco":12.12,"imagem":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/foto.jpg","url":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/"},{"produto":"nome item","quantidade":12,"preco":12.12,"imagem":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/foto.jpg","url":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/"},{"produto":"nome item","quantidade":12,"preco":12.12,"imagem":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/foto.jpg","url":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/"},{"produto":"nome item","quantidade":12,"preco":12.12,"imagem":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/foto.jpg","url":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/"},{"produto":"nome item","quantidade":12,"preco":12.12,"imagem":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/foto.jpg","url":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/"},{"produto":"nome item","quantidade":12,"preco":12.12,"imagem":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/foto.jpg","url":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/"},{"produto":"nome item","quantidade":12,"preco":12.12,"imagem":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/foto.jpg","url":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/"},{"produto":"nome item","quantidade":12,"preco":12.12,"imagem":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/foto.jpg","url":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/"},{"produto":"nome item","quantidade":12,"preco":12.12,"imagem":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/foto.jpg","url":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/"},{"produto":"nome item","quantidade":12,"preco":12.12,"imagem":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/foto.jpg","url":"http:\/\/site.com.br\/"}]"
}
```

Comment: Boa noite, ajudou em partes... consegui deixar o ["carrinho"] como eu gostaria... porem ele fica exatamente como vc postou, mas a API que estou integrando, o cara fez totalmente errado e antes do colchete nessa parte aqui `"[{"produto" :` ele não aceita essas aspas duplas... e nisso que estou com dificuldade

Comment: Coloque assim, 'carrinho' => "'$carrinho'"

Comment: O pessoal da API arrumou o jeito de receber as informações, e apenas com a sua primeira resposta solucionou meu caso, obrigado

Comment: Que bom ter ajudado.